# JS Testing: A contract calling a function in another contract which creates a contract

Tags: truffle, javascript, evm, ganache

I want to test three contracts in total: `Main.sol`, `Factory.sol`, `PCE.sol`

Here's the flow I want:

1. `accounts[0]` calls factoryStart in `Main.sol`
2. `Main.sol` should call a function in `Factory.sol`, passing the address of `accounts[0]`
3. `Factory.sol` should create/deploy a new `PCE.sol`, passing the args

Below is the half-working code. Parts of code are omitted for readability:

Main.sol

```
import '../factory/Factory.sol';

pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Main:
{

    Factory factory;
    uint256 factoryStartCount;

    constructor(address _factory)
    {
        factory = Factory(_factory);
    }


    function factoryStart(uint256 attr1, uint256 attr2) public payable 
    {  

        AM_ADDRESS = msg.sender;

        factory.newPCE( attr1, attr2, AM_ADDRESS);
        
        factoryStartCount++;

    }

    function getFactoryStartCount() public view returns(uint256)
    {
        return factoryStartCount;
    }

}
```

Factory.sol:

```
import '../PCE/PCE.sol';

pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Factory
{
 
  uint256 numPCE;

  function newPCE(uint256 attr1, uint256 attr2, address payable AM_ADDRESS) public payable 
  returns(PCE)
   {
       
    address payable VAULT  = 0x1B2F262A2320939001a0276FB335EAf7b6185e38;
        
    PCE cookie =  new PCE( attr1, attr2, AM_ADDRESS, VAULT) ;
            
    numPCE++;
    return cookie;
   }

    function getNumPCE() public view returns(uint256)
     {
      return numPCE;
     }
}
```

PCE.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract PCE{
 
  constructor (uint256 attr1, uint256 attr2, address payable AM_ADDRESS, address payable VAULT)
  {
   // do stuff
  }
  // do other stuff
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js :

```
const PCE_Factory     = artifacts.require("./Factory")
const Main            = artifacts.require("./Main");

module.exports = async function(deployer)
{
  
  await deployer.deploy(PCE_Factory);

  const Factory = await PCE_Factory.deployed();

  await deployer.deploy(Main, Factory.address);

};
```

test.js:

```
const Main          = artifacts.require("Main");
const Factory       = artifacts.require("Factory");

contract('Main', async (accounts) =>
{
    before( async() => {

        instance_factory = await Factory.new()
        instance_main    = await Main.new(Factory.address);

    });

   it('PCE can be created upon request: TEST.A', async() => {

        try{

        await instance_main.factoryStart.call( 2 , 5 
            {from: accounts[0] } );
        }

        catch(error){

        console.log(error);
        };

    });


    it('should increment factoryStartCount: TEST.B ', async() => {

        let factoryCount        = await instance_main.getFactoryStartCount.call();
        let int_factoryCount    = new BigNumber(factoryCount)

        console.log('       The factory has been initiated ' +int_factoryCount.toString() + ' times');
        assert.equal(1,int_factoryCount.toString());

    });


    it('should increment numPCE: TEST.C', async() => {

        let currentPCE    = await instance_factory.getNumPCE.call();
        let int_CurrentPCE = new BigNumber(currentPCE);

        console.log('       There are ' + int_CurrentPCE.toString() + 'PCE.' );
        assert.equal(1,int_CurrentPCE.toString());
        
    });
})
```

The interesting part is TEST.A passes, but TEST.B and TEST.C fail. I don't understand how TEST.A can pass without incrementing factoryStartCount and/or numPCE. Where am I mistaken ?

TEST.B and TEST.C outputs are both zero.

Any and all help is appreciated.

node: v12.18.4
ganache-cli: v6.12.1
Truffle v5.1.49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The mistake was that I was getting the wrong address in testing.js before function.

**Wrong version:**

```
before( async() => {

        instance_factory = await Factory.new()
        instance_main    = await Main.new(Factory.address);

    });
```

**Correct version:**

```
before( async() => {

        instance_factory = await Factory.new()
        instance_main    = await Main.new(instance_factory.address);

    });
```

Also as Ismael pointed out :

Since the code uses .call() when invoking the transaction any change will be discarded.

If you want to persist the modifications call like this:

```
await instance_main.factoryStart(2 , 5 
    { from: accounts[0] }
);
```